# “InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application”

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying to implement identityServer4  with [Asp.netIdentity.Mongo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Contrib.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB) with support for registration, 2fa and email confirmation. But i get  “InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application” when I run the code.

```
   services
           .AddIdentityWithMongoStores(connection)
           .AddDefaultMongoTokenProviders();

 services.AddIdentityServer(
                 options =>
                 {
                     options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                     options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                     options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                 }
             )
             .AddMongoRepository()
             .AddMongoDbForAspIdentity<ApplicationUser, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB.IdentityRole>(Configuration)
             .AddClients()
             .AddIdentityApiResources()
             .AddPersistedGrants()
             .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
             .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```